# Assigning an environment variable's value to a helm variable

Tags: ruby, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I'm new to helm and I want to be able to write gitlab project variables to files using config maps and shared environment variables.

I have a set of environment variables defined as gitlab project variables (the gitlab runner exposes them as environment variables) for each environment (where `<ENV>` is DEV/TEST/PROD for the sake of brevity):

```
MYSQL_USER_<ENV> = "user"
MYSQL_PASSWORD_<ENV> = "pass"
```

In the helm chart every environment has a map of its variables. For example, values.<ENV>.yaml contains:

```
envVars:
  MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER_<ENV>
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD_<ENV>
```

`values.yaml` contains a Ruby file which will consume those variables:

```
files:
  config.rb: |
    mysql['username'] = ENV["MYSQL_USER"]
    mysql['password'] = ENV["MYSQL_PASSWORD"]
```

configmap.env.yaml defines:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}-config-env
data:
{{- range $config_key, $config_value := .Values.envVars }}
  {{ $config_key }}: {{ $config_value | quote | nindent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```

configmap.files.yaml defines:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}-config-volume
data: 
{{- range $file_path, $file_content := .Values.files }}
  {{ $file_path }}: |
{{ $file_content | indent 4 -}}
{{- end }}
```

Finally, the deployment of the config map (only the config map part is shown here and I'm not using secrets here because this question is long enough as it is):

```
      volumes:
        - name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}-config-volume
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          volumeMounts:
          - name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}-config-volume
            mountPath: /etc/my-config-dir
          envFrom: 
            - configMapRef:
                name: {{ include "mychart.fullname" . }}-config-env
```

So, in one sentence the workflow should be:
`MYSQL_USER/PASSWORD_<ENV>` saved into `MYSQL_USER/PASSWORD`, which are then written to `/etc/my-config-dir/config.rb`

I can't seem to make the environment variables of values.yaml (`MYSQL_USER`, `MYSQL_PASSWORD`) get the *value* of the project variables (`MYSQL_USER_<ENV>`, `MYSQL_PASSWORD_<ENV>`).
I use helm 3, but `{{ env "MYSQL_USER_<ENV>" }}` fails.
I could use string interpolation with the environment variable's name it the Ruby file, but then I would have to know what environment variables should be created for every container.

I'm trying to avoid having multiple `--set` arguments. Also I'm not sure how `envsubst` can be used here...

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I guess I'll have to write the environment variables to a file and export them... When I get to this I'll create an answer.

Comment: You might find it more convenient to write out the variables as a JSON file.  Helm will accept a JSON-format values file in a `helm install -f` option.  (...because valid JSON is valid YAML.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I agree, but unfortunately I have to use gitlab project variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So eventually I used `envsubst`:

```
  script:
    - VALUES_FILE=values.${ENV}.yaml
    - envsubst < ${VALUES_FILE}.env > ${VALUES_FILE}
    - helm upgrade ... -f ${VALUES_FILE}
```